# Get Request not returning values from ionic framework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Trying to call an API which returns First Name and Last name from Ionic Framework.API works well from postman well. But called from ionic framework, not getting the desired output. can you please guide.

Ionic Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PeopleService } from '../../providers/people-service/people-service';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers: [PeopleService]
})
export class HomePage {
  public people: any;

  constructor(public peopleService:any) {
    this.loadPeople();
  }

  loadPeople() {
    this.peopleService.load()
      .then(data => {
        this.people = data;
      });
  }


  onLink(url: string) {
      window.open(url);
  }
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Home
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="#person of people">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{studentData.ProfileImageId}}">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{studentData.FirstName}} {{studentData.LastName}}</h2>
      <p>{{studentData.ContactEmail}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks.
Sudharsan

Comment: What does the `peopleService` look like? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: We are not getting any errors. It blank screen. There is no any message in console. People Service returns ID, first name, last name, email id, Profile photo.

Comment: Thank You Richard.